# Get/Set function to change text and color

Tags: c++, oop

Im trying to make a class called Label. Labels are plain text controls. One should be able to change the text and color of a label through get/set functions. I think this is a way to change the text of the label through get/set function. But Im not sure about the color. Any advice would be appriciated.

```
<pre>

class Label
{
private:
    std::string text;
    int color;

public:
    Label();

    void SetText(string Ntext);
    void SetColor(int value);
    int GetColor();
    string GetText();
    ~Label();
};

<code>
<pre>
Label::Label()
{
}

string Label::GetText()
{
    return text;
}

void Label::SetText(string Ntext)
{
    text = Ntext;
}

int Label::GetColor()
{
    return color;
}

void Label::SetColor(int value)
{
    color = value;
}

Label::~Label()
{
}

<code>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Colours are usually defined as RGB or HSV. RGB is probably the easiest. So store the colour as three distinct values - `unsigned char` perhaps.

Comment: Question was if im doing it right or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You'll get the answer when you start to use this code to solve your problem

Comment: Well I suppose, But this is a project between many people. And I just don't wanna come there looking like a fool.

Answer (score 0):

You can make color an array containing red blue and green.

```
int color[3];

void SetColor(int red, int green, int blue){
this->color[0] = red;
this->color[1] = green;
this->color[2] = blue;
}
```

Comment: If I do it like this, I'll return color[3]; from get color? instead of just returning color?

Comment: You can't have color in one variable, you must store it in 3 variables and display it with a function from the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the question of how to represent the color (which actually varies depending on how the class will be used, for example, it can be something as simple as `red`, `black`, `white`, etc strings), another thing to consider is that having getters and setters is not good in terms of OOP.

The idea of OOP is to hide the data inside the objects and instruct these objects to do something useful (send them messages).

With getters and setters you open the internal implementation (it is actually the same as if you define the `text` and `color` as public properties. It doesn't sound good, right? But this is actually what it is, you can read and modify them as if they are public.

So the better implementation could be to have both text and color to be constructor parameters. This way label has enough information to be displayed, so you don't need to have setters / getters, something like this:

```
class Label
{
private:
    std::string text;
    int color;

public:
    Label(string text, string color);
    ~Label();

    // display the label on the `canvas`
    void display(Canvas* canvas);
};
```

More information on the topic of getters / setters:

- [Why getter and setter methods are evil](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html)
- [More on getters and setters](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072302/core-java/more-on-getters-and-setters.html)
- [Getters/Setters. Evil. Period.](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html)